# Fetch text but insert as html, jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, plaintext

So I want to build an ajax website that fetches pages using api requests which will return the results in plain-text but I want jQuery to load it into the page as HTML is that possible?

Comment: yes set contentType to html

Comment: Just use jQuery.append(): https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Where is your code ? What you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you describe "plain-text"? `html` elements as a text string, or text content which should be set as `.innerHTML` of an existing element?

Comment: content-encoding:plain-text, as then insert it as html that way it wouldn't be &lt;div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following to get content in a specific div from an HTML document and append it to an element.  In the example, `#treatment` is the id of the div in the external document:

```
var content = 'external_page.html';

$.get(content, function(data){
     var el = $('<div>').html(data).find('#treatment');
     el.hide().appendTo('#content_frame_right').fadeIn(500);
});
```

The `hide` is there to enable the `fadeIn`, if you don't want the `fadeIn`, then just use:

```
el.appendTo('#content_frame_right');
```

You can use the simple PHP library called html2text to convert the HTML doc to text on import.  See https://github.com/mtibben/html2text

Or for a JavaScript solution you could use [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2)

Comment: I know how to get content, lets say I have a file that contains html code(use php to change - content-encoding:plain-text), how would you do that?

Comment: Thanks but you do not understand my point because I didn't elaborate on my statement, what I meant was that I have a file that will contain html code and will be loaded as plain-text but I want to get certain content afterwards, by now it seems like a useless question, I see it will put load on server and users' PC, is it better to just pull html out?

Comment: Well you could get the specific html section as I have described in my answer using divs.  Then strip the html using regex: string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");